# Return the actual connected DAG data from Apache Airflow Rest API, such that one can build their own UI to visualize the DAGs

Tags: api, rest, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using the [Apache Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html).

There are a number of basic commands supported. For example I can return a specific DAG's info by running:

```
https://8080/my_url/api/experimental/dags/example_pig_operator/dag_runs
```

...which returns:

```
[{
    "dag_id": "example_pig_operator",
    "dag_run_url": "/admin/airflow/graph?dag_id=example_pig_operator&execution_date=2021-06-18 19:57:31+00:00",
    "execution_date": "2021-06-18T19:57:31 00:00",
    "id": 4,
    "run_id": "manual__2021-06-18T19:57:31 00:00",
    "start_date": "2021-06-18T19:57:31.474920 00:00",
    "state": "running"
}]
```

But this doesn't tell you what's connected to what. I cannot see how to retrieve that actual DAG data used to construct the tree.

Is there a way to return the actual connected DAG data such that one could build their own UI to visualize the DAGs?

It seems like we should be able to use the `TaskInstance` [endpoint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/TaskInstance), but I cannot see how to get the `dag_run_id`

Answer (score 0):

Your request calls for DAG runs not DAGs. The experimental API does not support retriving DAGs. Please consider migrating to Airflow 2.0 with new [REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) because 1.10.X reached end of life yesterday (17th of June).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation around how to install the plugin for the newer REST API version. Any ideas where to get this plugin?

Comment: The new API is not a plugin. You need to [upgrade your Airflow to 2+ version](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html)